# Angular JS directive two way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to use two way binding and it isn't working. This is in my controller's init function:

```
$scope.custName = "";
```

This is how I am loading the directive page:

```
<product-selection cust-name="custName"></product-selection>
```

In my product selection directive I take the custName parameter like this:

```
scope: {
        custName: '='
       },
```

And this is the input in the directive page:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text"
                   id="inputName"
                   name="inputName"
                   ng-model="custName"/>
        </div>
```

When I update the textbox I see the change at any breakpoint in the directive, $scope.custName shows the updated value. But the value in the controller never updates. Why is that?

Comment: $scope.$parent is what I needed